# How do i include opencv into my catkin_workspace?

Tags: opencv, cmake, catkin

I am currently having issues with the `find_package(opencv)` which give me the error message:

```
 -- Could not find the required component 'OpenCV'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

So.. Yeah, a solution would add the prefix_path, but how do i make it work with `find_package()` without explicitly stating the path it has to look for.. why can't it find it in the first place, the problem by doing this is that the CMakelist is shared amongst a group a people, in which I am the only one having this issue despite, having the .cmake file at the same location..

I am running it on a ubuntu machine.

OpenCV v2.4.8

And the .cmake files are located at

/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake

opencv is installed as `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`

Comment: `why can't it find it in the first place?` - Because `find_package()` **doesn't search entire filesystem**, it searches only *some default paths*. If you install OpenCV into other path, it cannot be found without some hints (like setting *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH*).

Comment: So how do i find out where it search for it.

Comment: Search algorithm is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) to `find_package()`. If you only want to install `catkin`, there is no needs to understand the algorithm in details, just follow what error message suggests.

Comment: thats the problem.. The cmakelist is shared amongst a group of people.. I am the only one having the issue despite having the .cmake located at the same position..

Comment: Then provide additional information about your **actual problem**: where (which installation prefix) you have OpenCV installed, how have you installed it (via package manager, or manually from sources), and what distro do you use. Add this information into the question post (via [edit]).

Comment: Call for `find_package()` at [catkinConfig.cmake:83](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake.in#L83) explicitely disables search in default paths using *NO_DEFAULT_PATH* option. Instead, it uses *PATH* option with directories from variable *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH*, which is filled in [all.cmake](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/cmake/all.cmake). So, the difference between yours and others installation may be in things other than installation paths. E.g., it could be a difference in `catkin` installations.